# sprintf new line not working

Tags: php, arrays, printf

I am trying to format an array of string data using sprintf but for some reason I can't get it to print a new line. I want the new line to be started after line_1 is returned. Here is the code that I have. Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to using sprintf so I may be doing this wrong.

```
function format_address($address_array) {
return sprintf( "%s \n %s %s %s \t %s",
    $address_array['line_1'],
    $address_array['city'],
    $address_array['state'],
    $address_array['zip'],
    $address_array['line_5']
    );
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove \n and \t out of the function? Where are you using the function? Finally, are all of the fields set in the array? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @LiamSorsby Well the function itself is working no matter what, it is the formatting that is not taking effect. So yes technically it works without those in it but it is not formatting correctly.

Comment: What is being displayed instead? Is this being displayed in HTML? or just in plain text?

Comment: @LiamSorsby It is being displayed in HTML and it is just being displayed all on one line.

Comment: The "\n" will only display a line break in plain text. If you view the source code does it look correct? if so replace these with proper HTML line breaks ect.

Comment: @LiamSorsby Ah ha! I see! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Not a problem. I gather it's working now. I would like to point out that it's actually faster to concatenate, more so with single quotes than double quotes, then it is to use sprintf however it's very minor and sprintf looks nicer. The difference however will not be noticable unless you use it 200,000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to formalize the answer so that this question may be marked as "solved" based on Liam's suggestion:

```
function format_address($address_array) {
    return sprintf( "%s <br/> %s %s %s \t %s",
        $address_array['line_1'],
        $address_array['city'],
        $address_array['state'],
        $address_array['zip'],
        $address_array['line_5']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just concatenate?

```
return $address_array['line_1']."\n".$address_array['city']."\n".$address_array['state']."\n".$address_array['zip']."\n".$address_array['line_5'];
```

Also, it's worth noting in PHP to use line breaks correctly, you'll need to be sure to use `"\n"` and not `'\n'`